# Join two sql's to return articles and its likes

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am new to Oracle and need help with the following: I am having a sql which returns a list of articles-

```
SELECT LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ID
    , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_TITL_DESC
    , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_CNTNT_TXT
    , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT
    , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
    , LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_URL
    , LEADERSHIP.ARTCL_SRC_ID
    , MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP 
FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER LEADERSHIP 
INNER JOIN RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE MEDIA 
    ON (LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF) 
WHERE (LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
    , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT) 
IN (SELECT LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
      , MAX(LDRSHP_PUBD_DT) 
    FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER 
    GROUP BY LDRSHP_ATHR_NM) 
ORDER BY LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT DESC
```

I have to implement total likes for each articles which is returned by this sql

```
SELECT LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_ID
, COUNT(*) TOTAL_LIKES 
FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER LEADERSHIP1
, RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERS_LIKES LIKES1 
WHERE LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_ID = LIKES1.LDRSHP_ID 
group by LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_I
```

Now I need a single sql by combining above two sql's to return all the articles along with the total likes for each article. I will really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Look up the `union all` function. Are you wanting to `sum(TOTAL_LIKES)` based on the `select` above??

Comment: First of all, please format your SQL so that it's readable. Second, post table definitions and some sample data.

Comment: Hi @Hector I do not want to do sum total of like. The second sql returns total like count for each article id but here I want to display the total like's with the first sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join them. You have to use a left outer join. Otherwise the articles that didn't get any "like" yet, wouldnt be displayed.

```
SELECT A.LDRSHP_ID
    , A.LDRSHP_TITL_DESC
    , A.LDRSHP_CNTNT_TXT
    , A.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT
    , A.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
    , A.MEDIA_URL
    , A.ARTCL_SRC_ID
    , A.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP 
    , B.TOTAL_LIKES
FROM
    (
            SELECT LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ID
                   , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_TITL_DESC
                  , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_CNTNT_TXT
                  , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT
                  , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
                  , LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_URL
                  , LEADERSHIP.ARTCL_SRC_ID
                  , MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_DESCRIP 
              FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER LEADERSHIP 
              INNER JOIN RSKLMOBILEB2E.MEDIA_TYPE MEDIA 
                  ON (LEADERSHIP.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF = MEDIA.MEDIA_TYPE_IDENTIF) 
              WHERE (LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
                  , LEADERSHIP.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT) 
              IN (SELECT LDRSHP_ATHR_NM
                    , MAX(LDRSHP_PUBD_DT) 
                  FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER 
                  GROUP BY LDRSHP_ATHR_NM) 
      ) A 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (
              SELECT LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_ID
              , COUNT(*) TOTAL_LIKES 
              FROM RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERSHIP_CORNER LEADERSHIP1
              , RSKLMOBILEB2E.LEADERS_LIKES LIKES1 
              WHERE LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_ID = LIKES1.LDRSHP_ID 
              group by LEADERSHIP1.LDRSHP_I
      ) B
              ON (A.LDRSHP_ID=B.LDRSHP_ID)
      ORDER BY A.LDRSHP_PUBD_DT DESC
```

Comment: It works perfect with LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.
Thanks you so much. This was indeed helpful.

Comment: @PankajDubey: I missed this. I changed to join to an outer join.